# Problem running code for iOS in flutter(androidstudio)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio

[image][image]I do not know where the problem is, please help me

this is my code:

```
  _askPermission() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      Map<PermissionGroup , PermissionStatus> permissions =
      await PermissionHandler()
          .requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.photos]);
    } else {
      PermissionStatus permission = await PermissionHandler()
          .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.storage);
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: seems perfect but what you're looking for

Comment: Please Attach a screenshot with error, that would be helpful to answer your question.

Comment: @MohanSaiManthri I did

Comment: What is the error you're getting exactly? Have you imported necessary things like dart.io etc

Comment: @MohanSaiManthri                                                                                                import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Comment: @nafashmn.ir try to do invalidate catche and restart studio.

Comment: @hardikpatel  I did, the problem was not solved

Comment: @nafashmn.ir Please share the error, you can hover on the error & share the screenshot.

Comment: @MohanSaiManthri i did

Comment: if possible could you provide anydesk id ? so we can look closer to the error @nafashmn.ir

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you're using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler
and in that package I didn't see

> PermissionHandler() or PermissionGroup()

If you want request bulk, this is what you should do

```
Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
  Permission.location,
  Permission.storage,
].request();
print(statuses[Permission.location]);
```

Check this for more help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64646086/10711216